# MATLAB: fill array with numbers in increments

Tags: arrays, matlab

I'd like to have a MATLAB array fill a column with numbers in increments of 0.001. I am working with arrays of around 200,000,000 rows and so would like to use the most efficient method possible. I had considered using the following code:

```
for i = 1 : size(array,1)
    array(i,1) = i * 0.001;
end
```

There must be a more efficient way of doing this..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
array(:,1) = [1:size(array,1)]' * 0.001;
```

Matlab is more efficient when vectorizing loops, see also the [performance tips](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f8-784135.html) from mathworks.

If such vectorization is infeasible due to space limitations, you might want to reconsider rewriting your for-loop in C, using a [MEX](http://www.mathworks.nl/support/tech-notes/1600/1605.html#intro) function.

Comment: As g24l pointed out, the transpose is not needed, and even negatively affects performance. I incorrectly assumed Matlab would optimize this (yes, stupid me).

Answer (score 9):

Well the accepted answer is pretty close to being fast but no fast enough. You should use:

```
s=size(array,1);
step=0.0001;
array(:,1)=[step:step:s*step];
```

There are two issues with the accepted answer

1. you don't need to transpose
2. you should include the step inside the vector, instead of multiplying

and here is a comparison (sorry I am running 32-bit matlab)

```
array=rand(10000);

s=size(array,1);
step=0.0001;
tic
for i=1:100000
array(:,1)=[step:step:s*step];
end
toc
```

and

```
tic
for i=1:100000
array(:, 1)=[1:s]'*step;
end
toc
```

the results are:

Elapsed time is 3.469108 seconds.

Elapsed time is 5.304436 seconds.

and without transposing in the second example

Elapsed time is 3.524345 seconds.

I suppose in your case things would be worst.

Comment: +1 for correct use of the `start:step:end` syntax for evenly-spaced lists.

Comment: @catchmeifyoutry +1 for you nickname :D

Answer (score 1):

you can also try this

`size=20000000;%size is defined`

`array(1:size,1)=(1:size)*0.001`

Comment: `array(:,1)` implies `array(1:size,1)`